# Cannot seem to update my shared libraries path

Tags: shared-library

I am trying to add a library folder to my Ubuntu system.

The library folder I am trying to update the system with is: `/home/user/programs/elastix/lib`.

I have tried the following things:
I first checked `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ervironmental variable:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64
```

And it just contains 1 folder (?). Anyway I checked `ld.so.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf

include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

and just included all config files in `ld.so.conf.d` folder.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  38 Nov 24  2014 fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 108 Jan 15  2018 i386-linux-gnu.conf   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  41 May 15  2018 i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  40 May 15  2018 i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf ->  /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44 Jan 27  2016 libc.conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38 Nov 14 17:16 randomLibs.conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26 May 17 10:44 tensorflow_lib.conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68 Apr 15  2016 x86_64-linux-gnu.conf   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  43 May 15  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  42 Sep 14 17:16 x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf -> > /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56 Jan 15  2018 zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf
```

It contains 11 config files. This seems rather peculiar since 1 link for 11 (non empty) config files does not make sense.

I added manually the folder to the `ld.so.conf` file:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf

include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf  
/home/user/programs/elastix/lib
```

and run

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

to update the cache. This error message occurs and I guess nothing is updated also.

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.7 is not a symbolic link

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64
```

The only way I can make it work is by specifically adding the folder in console:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/programs/elastix/lib
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/home/user/programs/elastix/lib
```

So, my question is what's going on here? Why my shared libraries are not updated using `ldconfig` and why I can only see 1 folder in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also?

According to this [post](http://howtolamp.com/articles/adding-shared-libraries-to-system-library-path/) I could move my shared libraries to these folders:

- /lib/
- /usr/lib/
- /usr/local/lib/

and make it work but I would like to know what's the problem with the previous approach.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.

Comment: Please code formatting for command output, not quote formatting.

Comment: And how it would be distinguished by command evoking?

Comment: Put a `$` in front of the command.

Answer (score 1):

There is a naming convention for shared object libraries:

The "real" library file should be named `libcudnn.so.7.0`. From that file two soft links should be created:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.7 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.0
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.0 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.7
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.0 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudnn.so
```

This allows the compiler to be called with the `-lcudnn` switch. Also `ldconfig` seams to verify this convention. See also this ([link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)).